# How to get attribute of select.options in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the property of `option` in `for` loop. But my usecases are not working here. Can anyone please help.

```
for (var y = 0; y < $('select option').length; y++){
    this.options[y].attr('disabled'); // Not working (attr is not a function)
    this.options[y].prop('disabled'); // Not working (prop is not a function)
  }
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo" disabled>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw" disabled>VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `this.options[y]` refers to DOM element, not jQuery Object. Wrap it in `$` like `$(this.options[y])`

Comment: @Rayon is right, use elements with jQuery and use `prop({disabled: true/false})`

Comment: It's also more idiomatic in jQuery to use `$('select option').each(...)` rather than a basic `for` loop

Comment: @Roy - OP is trying to get the value as it states _I'm trying to get the property of option_.

Comment: @Znaneswar Please accept the answer that suits you best if your problem is solved so we can see you got an answer. You got plenty to choose from :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
for (var y = 0; y < $('select option').length; y++){
    $(this.options[y]).attr('disabled'); // Not working (attr is not a function)
    $(this.options[y]).prop('disabled'); // Not working (prop is not a function)
  }
```

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo" disabled>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw" disabled>VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wgv7hL5p/

Hope you got the expected.

Answer (score 3):

Why not using jQuery's [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```js
 $('select option').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
 });
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo" disabled>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw" disabled>VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the working example:-

```js
    var selectedOptions = $('select option')
    
    for (var y = 0; y < selectedOptions.length; y++){
       console.log(selectedOptions[y].disabled) 
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="volvo" disabled>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw" disabled>VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help (no jquery needed)

```js
var options = document.querySelectorAll('select option');
options.forEach(function(option) {
    console.log(
        "Value: " + option.value, 
        " disabled: " + option.disabled, 
        " selected: " + option.selected
    );
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo" disabled>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw" disabled>VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter()` function to select the disabled elements and then loop over them with the `each()` function.

The `prop()` is the correct one to use for properties. You want to use `attr()` for attributes only.

```js
$('select option').filter(function(){
  return $(this).prop('disabled');
}).each(function(){
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="volvo" disabled>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw" disabled>VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the elements with the `each` function:

```js
$('select option').each((i, e) => {
  console.log("option " + i + " disbaled = " + $(e).attr('disabled'));
  console.log("option " + i + " selected = " + $(e).attr('selected'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="volvo" disabled>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw" disabled>VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jquery

```
$("#select option").each(function(i){
    var option = $(this);
    console.log(option.text() + " : " + option.val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can achieve this doing this kinda stuff also

```js
for (var y = 0; y <= $('select option').length; y++){
 $('select option').eq(y).prop('disabled',true);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="volvo" disabled>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw" disabled>VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```